# SQL para mês passado e bimestre passado

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select, data

Olá. Eu gostaria de uma ajuda aqui. 
Preciso pegar os registros:
Banco MySQL
1) mês passado 2) bimestre passado 3) Ano atual

```
SELECT id, data, lote, modelo, qtd FROM controle_diario WHERE modelo like ?
```

A tabela é muito simples: id é auto-increment, lote é varchar, modelo é varchar e qtd é int. Exemplo:

```
id - data - modelo - qtd  
1 - 2017-04-20 - 10001 - 100  
2 - 2017-04-22 - 10002 - 10  
3 - 2017-05-10 - 100010 - 30  
4 - 2017-05-15 - 100020 - 60  
5 - 2017-05-16 - 100060 - 70  
6 - 2017-05-20 - 100010 - 100
```

Obrigado

Comment: Qual banco está utilizando ?

Comment: Qual banco está utilizando? Poderia editar sua pergunta exibindo alguns dados de exemplo da tabela ou utilizar algo semelhante ao http://sqlfiddle.com/?

Comment: Ok. Pergunta Editada!

Comment: Pelo que vi o campo data não é do tipo date ou datetime, certo?

Comment: Não percebi ali. Mas sim, o capo data é DATE. Transformo dentro do Java para ir para o banco.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Mês passado:**

```
SELECT id, data, lote, modelo, qtd FROM controle_diario *WHERE MONTH(data)=(MONTH(NOW())-1)*
```

**Ano atual:**

```
SELECT id, data, lote, modelo, qtd FROM controle_diario WHERE YEAR(data)=YEAR(NOW())
```

Correção proposta pelo Mauro Lacerda para a query Mês Passado:

```
WHERE MONTH(data)=MONTH(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) AND YEAR(data)=YEAR(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda Rovann Linhalis

Comment: Por nada. A parte do bimestre fica um tanto subjetivo, pois posso entender como primeiro bimestre, janeiro e fevereiro. Porém talvez sua necessidade seja Fevereiro e março. Mas usando a opção de mês você consegue fazer o que precisa.

Comment: Ok. Eu fiz o que precisei aqui. Deixei os dois meses anteriores a minha data atual. Obrigado

Comment: Mês passado: assim não funciona pois se for janeiro vai dar ruim: `WHERE MONTH(data)=(MONTH(NOW())-1)` o que funciona certo é assim: `WHERE MONTH(data)=MONTH(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)) AND YEAR(data)=YEAR(ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))`

Answer (score 3):

1)`SELECT id, data, lote, modelo, qtd FROM controle_diario WHERE MONTH(data) = ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)`

3) Para o bimestre passado talvez tenha que ter mais alguma verificação, mas isso pode lhe dar uma origem para a solução:

`SELECT id, data, lote, modelo, qtd FROM controle_diario WHERE MONTH(data) >= ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -4 MONTH) AND MONTH(data) <= ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)`

3)`SELECT id, data, lote, modelo, qtd FROM controle_diario WHERE YEAR(data) = YEAR(NOW())`

Comment: Obrigado Roberto Fagundes.